# How can I add same extension point in multiple plugin project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I have three plugin projects which collectively constitute a feature for eclipse. And I have an another project which deals with licensing and other stuffs. I have created an extension point in the licensing plugin and successfully connected this to one of my project.But when I repeat the same procedure for second project it throws some error like

> "Access restriction", "A cycle was detected in the build path of project".

Please help me guys, I am completely new to plugin development 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an extension point problem. More likely circular dependencies in the plugins (A depends on B and B depends on A). You need to show us more details of the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [When to use import package and require bundle](http://techshashwat.blogspot.in/2015/05/when-to-use-import-package-and-require.html)